# What am I looking for in probability plots?

Tags: data-transformation, dataset

I have some heavily skewed data and would like to try and transform it to be approximately normal.

Here is a histogram of the transformed data[image]

The transformed data leads to a rejection of the null for python's implementation of the `shapiro` and `normaltest` hypothesis tests.  I read that a probability plot may be a good way to check for normality.

Here is a QQ plot

[image]

The data seems to be linear, good R squared, but I am not sure what to make of the lower left and upper right corners of the plot.

Is this a good fit?  Can I proceed using the data as "normal" or should I act on what the normality tests tell me?

Comment: Your data are discrete, with substantial spikes at the lowest values. You can't do more than move those spikes around a little but with monotonic transformation you can't change their order so it's never going to look very different at the low end

Comment: $R^2$ is useless for Q-Q plots because by construction it's guaranteed to be large.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see your data is slightly long tailed, which is usually not a problem for Gaussian models. Of course you would get better results modelling the tail also. However it depends on the level of accuracy you need to achieve in your modelling.

Comment: You are right, the data is long tailed.  It is the total spend for a particular customer base.  Most customers spend around 100-150 dollars per month.  There are a handful of customers that spend upwards of 250,000 per month.  Do you have any suggestions for modelling the tail?  I can provide a histogram of the original data if need be.

Comment: Well I just read about it, I never actually worked with it. Try first to quantile plot a lognormal distribution, maybe it fits better. At that point you can work in a log space using Gaussian models

Comment: The *transformed* data, as shown in the question, are *short* tailed, not long tailed.  In many applications, though, the slight discrepancy would be of no consequence.  If the transformation indeed was the logarithm, it does suggest there is danger in modeling the original dataset as lognormal, because estimates of the mean, variance, and upper quantiles may be (substantially) too large.